# Display name of Identity User who created and last updated record when ID is saved

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, razor, asp.net-identity

I must not be searching with the correct phrases.  This is a simple concept and I’ve done it in other languages and frameworks with ease.

I’m saving the UserID for the person who created the record and the UserID who last updated the record.  Instead of displaying the UserID, I want to display the User.FirstName + ‘ ‘ + User.LastName.

The way I have it currently the LastEditBy and  CreateBy is displayed on the page as blank.

Controller:  I get the customer model and manually map the model to the customerViewModel then pass it to my partial view.

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int customerId)
    {
        Customer customer = DbContext.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerId == customerId);

        CustomerViewModel customerViewModel = MapToViewModel(customer);
        customerViewModel.UserSelectList = GetUserGroupList();
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationUserManager>();

        var CreateByUser = _userManager.FindById(customerViewModel.CreateById);
        var EditByUser = _userManager.FindById(customerViewModel.LastEditById);

        customerViewModel.CreateBy = CreateByUser.FirstName + " " + CreateByUser.LastName;
        customerViewModel.LastEditBy = EditByUser.FirstName + " " + EditByUser.LastName;
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
            return PartialView("_CustomerEditPartial", customerViewModel);
        }

        return View("_CustomerEditPartial", customerViewModel);
    }
```

The CustomerViewModel:

```
public class CustomerViewModel : DbContext{
    public CustomerViewModel(): base("name=CustomerViewModel")
    {
    }
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128), ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public SelectList UserSelectList { get; set; }

     #region additional Fields
     // This overrides default conventions or data annotations
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your first name.")]
     [StringLength(50)]
     [Display(Name = "First Name")]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your last name.")]
     [StringLength(100)]
     [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
     public string LastName { get; set; }

     [DataType(DataType.Date)]
     [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
     public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

     public string CreateById { get; set; }

     [NotMapped]
     public string CreateBy { get; set; }

     public string LastEditById { get; set; }
     [NotMapped]
     public string LastEditBy { get; set; }

     [DataType(DataType.Date)]
     [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
     public DateTime LastEditDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

     public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

 }

 public class UserGroupList
 {
     public string Value { get; set; }
     public string Text { get; set; }
 }
```

My partial view page:  _CustomerEditPartial.cshtml

```
@model WOA.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel

<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" daa-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="True">x</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Customer</h4>
        </div>
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Customers", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnFailure = "OnFail" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" })) {
             <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <hr />
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomerId)
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, "UserId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserId, ViewData.Model.UserSelectList, "Select One", new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreateDate, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreateBy, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastEditBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastEditBy, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastEditDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastEditDate, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save changes" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function OnSuccess() {
                alert("success");
            }
            function OnFail() {
                alert("fail");
            }
            function OnComplete() {
                alert("Complete");
            }

        </script>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I have updated my code, it is working now, however I do not believe it is the proper way to do this.
I believe I should be able to return the additional values I need via Linq on the initial call and not make two more trips to the database for the additional values.
I have not been able to figure out a way to make this work with Linq.

Thank you in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: your declaration of the the properties as virtual tells me you are lazy loading those entities.  just remove the virtual keyword to load them. or change your query to include the lazy loaded entities

Comment: I modified the view model as shown below but now I receive a "The name 
CreateBy does not exist in context".    This is the same with the LastEditBy.
    [NotMapped]
    public string ApplicationUser CreateBy { get; set; }